# C program to print all numbers with different digits in interval

Tags: c, loops, numbers

I need to make a program in C, which outputs all numbers with different digits in interval entered by the user. Here is what I've come up with.

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(){
int n, m, k = 0, p, flag, last, temp;
do{
    printf("Enter m and n (m < n):\n"); scanf("%d %d", &m, &n);
    if (m < n) {
        break;
    }
    else printf("\Error- m > n! Try again.\n\n");
} while (k == 0);

printf("Numbers are:\n");
for (k = m; k <= n; k++) {
    p = k;
    flag = 0;
    if (p < 10) {
        flag = 1;
    }
    last = (p / 10) % 10 ;
    while (p > 0) {
        temp = p % 10; 
        p = p / 10; 
        if (temp == last ){ 
            flag = 1;                                              
        }
        last = temp; 
    }
    if (flag != 1) { 
        printf("%d ", k);
    }
}
getch();
return 0;
}
```

Example output:

```
Enter m and n (m < n):
100 130
Numbers are:
101 102 103 104 105 106 107 108 109 120 121 123 124 125 126 127 128 129 130
```

So the problem in this case is that it outputs 101 and 121. It shouldn't because they have two same digits. How do I fix that?

Comment: Clearly, with `temp` and `last` you're only comparing each digit with the one before it. You have to compare each digit with *all* the others. There are many ways to do that.

Comment: ... such as a status array with 10 elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally made it to work!

```
int main(){
int n, m, k = 0, p = 0, flag, i = 0, j, dig[10];
do{
    printf("Enter m and n (m < n):\n"); scanf("%d %d", &m, &n);
    if (m < n) {
        break;
    }
    else printf("\Error- m > n! Try again.\n\n");
} while (k == 0);

printf("Numbers in the interval [%d, %d] are:\n", m, n);
for (k = m; k <= n; k++){
    p = k;
    flag = 0;
    dig[i] = 0;
    i = 0;
    if (p < 10){ 
        continue;
    }   
    while (p > 0){ 
        dig[i] = p % 10;
        p = p / 10;
        i++;
    }
        dig[i] = -1;
        for (i = 0; dig[i] > -1; i++){ 
            for (j = i + 1; dig[j] > -1; j++){ 
                if (dig[i] == dig[j]){ 
                    flag = 1;
                }
            }
        }

        if (flag == 0){
            printf("%d\t", k);
        }
    }
getch();
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is the solution you're looking for. If you convert the numbers into strings it will be easier to check their digits. Note that you need two loops per number in the sequence. It's concise but it's still expensive. (Compile it using the flag *-std=c11*.)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    printf("Enter two non-negative numbers in ascending order:\n");
    int min, max;
    scanf("%d %d", &min, &max);

    while(min < 0 || max < 0 || min > max)
    {
        printf("Invalid input! Please enter two non-negative numbers in ascending order:\n");
        scanf("%d %d", &min, &max);
    }

    printf("The numbers without repeated digits in the interval [%d, %d] are:\n", min, max);

    for(int n = min; n <= max; ++n)
    {
        char digits[32];
        sprintf(digits, "%d", n);

        int repeated = 0;
        for(int i = 0; digits[i] && !repeated; ++i)
        {
            for(int j = i + 1; digits[j]; ++j)
            {
                if(digits[i] == digits[j])
                {
                    repeated = 1;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        if(!repeated) printf("%d ", n);
    }

    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: We still haven't studied how to use functions so I don't quite understand this :/

Comment: Talking about what you already learned or not: Have you looked into the most recent chapters of your text book or other course material? It probably has exactly the tools useable to solve this in the way the teacher expects.

Comment: Just Steve, I edited my answer with a code that doesn't make function calls. I suggest you to take a look and compare it with your solution, spotting the differences.